# Specific Format the Numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have `var number=11,070,489.0` with format function

```
  function formatNumber(num) {
        return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
    }
```

But i dont want to have `.0`. I want my number to have format like this `var number =11,070,489`

Comment: `num.split('.')[0]` can do the job

Comment: What's the input? `formatNumber(11070489)` returns `"11,070,489"`

Comment: Read this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp .

Comment: returns decimal 11070489.0

Comment: this is the input 11070489.0

Comment: i think split('.')[0]  done the job for me

Comment: @adiga I think the input is as string

Comment: @Cid why is OP doing `toString()` if the input is already a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex positive lookahead. (?=\.)

\d+(?=\.) this will select all numbers before a "."